# How's the view from Somerset House's terrace?

Tags: london, seasonal, vantage-points

Somerset House advertises that it's possible to watch the fireworks from their terrace on New Year's Eve - for a fee, of course. On the map they seem very close to the heart of things, but of course in reality that terrace might be completely surrounded by trees or something... so, has anyone been on that terrace, on New Year's Eve or at any other time, and can help me understand whether it's a good place to watch fireworks from?

I tried searching the internet for pictures taken from that place but could find almost nothing, which makes me worry it's not that good of a location.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are some trees between the terrace and the river ([sample photo](http://www.lady.co.uk/sites/default/files/image/15%20June%2010/Tom%27s-Terrace.jpg)), but they don't have any leaves on them in December and should not obstruct your view of the fireworks.

I have not been there on New Year's Eve myself though.